# Getting substrings with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

Given a string ' and d= 4 or eands = 5 or fxor = 6 and  or j = 6',

I need to get individual comparison filters i.e. d= 4, eands = 5, fxor =6, j = 6
I tried (.*)and(.*?) and some other expressions with no luck.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the regex: [`\s([^\s]+?\s?=\s?[^\s]+?)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/QcQ1gt/2).

In Python,

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\s([^\s]+?\s?=\s?[^\s]+?)\b',
               'and d= 4 or eands = 5 or fxor = 6 and or j = 6')
['d= 4', 'eands = 5', 'fxor = 6', 'j = 6']
```

Comment: if you take a whitespace between " 'and ", it prints and as well in output. but i ll change it as per my need.
otherwise, it works and thanks!

Comment: @ShubhamGupta Amended! It also gets the `'j = 6'` which it was missing before!

Answer (score 0):

[regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/jaapG9/4):

```
import re

s = 'and d= 4 or eands = 5 or fxor = 6 and or j = 6'

print(re.findall(r'\w+\s*=\s*\d+', s))
```

Prints:

```
['d= 4', 'eands = 5', 'fxor = 6', 'j = 6']
```